# How to trigger an Alert in View in Swift UI using a state from an enum in a singleton class

Tags: swift, swiftui

Assume a singleton class that has an enum about a login state as follows:

```
@Published var loginState: LoginState = .unknown
```

The singleton class instance is assigned as an `@ObservedObject` in the View to get changes from other `@Published` variables as follows:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @ObservedObject var loginDelegate = Singleton.shared
```

How do I trigger an Alert in a View using something like the following, when the singleton `loginState` is set to a certain enum case (for example `.error`)?

```
}.alert(isPresented: <something> ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following

```
}.alert(isPresented: .constant(loginDelegate.loginState == .error)) { ... }
```

but you will need to reset `loginDelegate.loginState` back to, say, `.unknown` in alert close button action, otherwise alert might re-appear immediately.